# GlassFish ASADMIN Deployment Command Specify context root with --name?

Tags: glassfish, asadmin

I am currently in the progress of configuring our dev environment to upgrade from the open source glassfish v3.1 to open source glassfish 3.1.2 and have noticed this difference between the versions using the asadmin command:

v3.1

deploy --name test:beta-1.0 "c:\tmp\my-long-test-app-war-name.war"

This is accessible via http:\\localhost:8080\test

v3.1.2

deploy --name test:beta-1.0 "c:\tmp\my-long-test-app-war-name.war"

This is only accessible via http:\\localhost:8080\my-long-test-app-war-name

I have noticed the --contextroot in the newer version which is described as:

```
 --contextroot
      Valid only if the  archive  is  a  web  module.  It  is
      ignored  for  other archive types; defaults to filename
      without extension.
```

And the --name as:

```
 --name
      Name of the deployable component.

      The name can include an  optional  version  identifier,
      which  follows  the name and is separated from the name
      by a colon (:). The version identifier must begin  with
      a letter or number. It can contain alphanumeric charac-
      ters plus underscore (_),  dash  (-),  and  period  (.)
      characters.  For  more  information  about  module  and
      application versions, see "Module and Application  Ver-
      sions"  in  Oracle GlassFish Server Application Deploy-
      ment Guide.
```

So for the newer versions (or whenever it changed above 3.1) should the deployment command become:

deploy --name test:beta-1.0 --contextroot test "c:\tmp\my-long-test-app-war-name.war"

Cheers,
Craig

ps currently trying to bring down v3.1.2.2 to test that but the corporate firewall is brutal

Answer (score 1):

I think both --contextroot and --name are corresponding to when you use the admin panel from the browser. They are independent to each other. Use --contextroot only if you want to change the default contextroot to a different one.